# Unauthorized Use of Special Function for Collection Containers in GridDB

Tags: database, griddb

So I was writing a TQL query on a collection container that I created using GridDB known as `MonthlyIncome` to store the monthly incomes of the employees of an organization. I wanted to calculate the unique average monthly income of the employees, which means avoiding duplicate income that the employees might have. The query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT AVG(DISTINCT Income) AS [Avg_Income]

FROM MonthlyIncome

WHERE Name ='Alex Benjamin'
```

But I received the following error.

```
[Error code]: 152003/152004

[Description] (Unauthorized use of special function for collection/time series containers)
```

From what I have understood from the above error, I think GridDB is not allowing the use of the `AVG()` function on the container, but I cannot figure out why. Any ideas?